# How to use EF default code generation strategy with separate files per object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

My project is using the "Default" code generation strategy for converting my EDMX into C# objects.
I don't want to change anything about the way the code is generated, except that I want to generate a separate file per generated class, rather than one big honkin' mutha of close on 100,000 lines.
What's the easiest way to achieve that?

**EDIT:** found the default template online, made a little tweak to it so that the generated output is identical to the original.  Code is too long to post here; you can [view it here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VTdo52vT5UdzV9s5coEqE9CV2PVpWBAfmlhdacTwjL8/edit?usp=sharing); now I need to know what modifications to make to it so that every generated class gets created in its own separate file.

Comment: What's the aim here? You can't edit those files, and you can view the class members much more easily in other places, like the Class View or the EDMX model itself.  Having said that, it's just a .tt code generation template under the hood, so you could probably alter it to generate separate files.

Comment: @anaximander - the aim is simply so that when I make changes and want to check them in to source control I can see at a glance which files were modified, as opposed to the current situation where I need to do a file diff to make sure I'm not inadvertently checking in something I didn't want to change.

Comment: Makes sense. Just checking because I've seen others asking similar questions where they wanted to edit the classes, not realising that editing generated code is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get to the .tt code generation template behind that EDMX, then you can set it to begin a new file per entity, something like this:

```
foreach (var entity in typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<EntityType>(itemCollection))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");
    BeginNamespace(code);
#>
(rest of class generation code here...)
```

where that `fileManager` is created thus:

```
var fileManager = EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(this);
```

and `BeginNamespace` should be further down the template; if you're missing it then it looks like this:

```
public void BeginNamespace(CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    var codeNamespace = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(codeNamespace))
    {
#>
namespace <#=code.EscapeNamespace(codeNamespace)#>
{
<#+
        PushIndent("    ");
    }
}

public void EndNamespace(CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(code.VsNamespaceSuggestion()))
    {
        PopIndent();
#>
}
<#+
    }
}
```

For reference, this is from the standard EF5 DbContext generator, which [can be found here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da740968-02f9-42a9-9ee4-1a9a06d896a2).

Comment: Searched for the .tt code generation template, couldn't find it.  Any idea where it is?

Comment: @Shaul Having checked, depending on your ADO.NET version you might not have a visible .tt; it'll be using the internal stuff. If that's the case then you might be stuck with implementing custom code generation, although there's likely to be a standard template out there that you could tweak - your aims are so close to the defaults, it'd be a relatively small change.

Comment: BeginNamespace() not found.  Where's the definition for that?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the older code generation stuff... Try installing the EF5 DbContext Generator template (if you don't have it already). If you're on the old stuff it might mean moving from an `ObjectContext` to a `DbContext`, but they're close to identical. Or, if you don't want to migrate, you could probably alter the template to produce an `ObjectContext` instead. I just migrated a reasonably-sized project myself; it doesn't take long.

Comment: I found the template code.  Definitely don't want to rock the boat by switching to `DbContext` at this point.  See edit to my question.

Comment: I definitely am missing something.  I'm comparing my .tt code to the stanard one.  Both make reference to objects like `CodeStringGenerator`, but my one fails compilation, because it can't find the type ("Missing assembly reference?")  Where is the reference set up?  How come one tt understands those types and the other doesn't?

Comment: So... that's odd. EF5 should use DbContext anyway; if you right-click in your EDMX, select Add Code Generation Item and pick the EF5 DbContext generator it gives you one file per type by default... so why do you have a single file?

Comment: I'm using the EntityContext generator.